# How to get duplicate month and year matched record in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to fetch duplicate month of record from table
I have leaves table inside of start_date column have many records my db
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFFkT.jpg
example I have 3 duplicate record in table 
return duplicate record#08.01.2019,31.01.2019,25.01.2019
How to do this ?

```
class LeaveController < ApplicationController
  def new
    #your code here 
  end
end
```

- My model name **Leave** my table name **leaves**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find duplicate dates by month when you're trying to find for all months in a single array
The below can give you an array of objects where your month number and duplicate dates for that month number will be there

#### For MySQL / PostgresQL

```
class LeaveController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @result = []
    12.times do |i|
      month_data = {
        month_number: i,
        duplicate_dates: Leave.where("extract(month from start_date) = ?", i).pluck(:start_date)
      }
      @result.push month_data
    end
    #Print and see the result
    p @result
  end
end
```

#### Update for SQLite

Since you're using sqlite, and the above syntax is not supported, here is a way for the same:

```
# In your model you can write a class method so you don't have to write all that
#   logic in your controller and make it reusable
class Leave < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.duplicate_dates(current_month)
    query = "SELECT * FROM leaves WHERE strftime('%m', start_date) = #{current_month}"
    self.find_by_sql query
  end
end

class LeaveController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @result = []
    ('01'..'12').to_a.each do |i|
      # Get all the records with duplicate month
      duplicate_data = Leave.duplicate_dates(i)
      # The above will return a regular array and not an activerecord association,
      #   so pluck can't be used on it

      # To get only the dates you can use map 
      duplicate_dates = duplicate_data.map {|i| i.start_date}

      month_data = {
        month_number: i,
        duplicate_dates: duplicate_dates
      }
      @result.push month_data
    end
    #Print and see the result
    p @result
  end
end
```

Comment: i am facing error SQLite3::SQLException: near "from": syntax error: SELECT "leaves"."start_date" FROM "leaves" WHERE (extract(month from start_date) = 0)

Comment: I've updated the code for SQLite as well. Please let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

On SQLite, you can't. The supported SQL features are really minimal, you'd better have a local postgres/mysql server - the same server and version you will be using in production.

On a real SQL database you have the `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from date)` function, and you can use it with `GROUP BY`.

This could be the proper SQL, you can use it with plain `Leave.connection.execute(...)`:

```sql
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(`leaves`.`id` SEPARATOR ',') AS ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`leaves`.`start_date` SEPARATOR ',') AS start_dates
FROM `leaves`
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from `leaves`.`start_date`)
HAVING COUNT(`leaves`.`id`) > 1
```

With the data in the image, you will have the following result:

```
ids               | start_dates
------------------+---------------------------------
5,6,8             | 2019-01-08,2019-01-31,2019-01-25
1,2,3,4           | ...
```

and there will be no entry for leaves that don't share month with others.